# How do you get rid of / from generating in the config file

Tags: php, html, config

I am trying to make a system where you can edit a config.php file from a webpage with a text field this is my code for the webpage but what happends is when I edit the config.php through the webpage here http://color-craft.info/dayzlegendz/controlpanel it replaces the " with / which stops the config from working

```
<?php

// First bring the actual value of the file:
$file = 'config.php';
// Uncomment next line to check if the file exists in the path
// print_r( glob( dirname(__FILE__) . "/*.php"  ) );

$configFile = html_entity_decode( file_get_contents($file) );

// On submit on the changes update the file
if ( isset( $_POST["save_button"] ) && $_POST["config_changes"]){
  # This doesn't work: $changes = $path = str_replace("\"", "'", $_POST["config_changes"]);
  file_put_contents($file, $_POST["config_changes"]);
}
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] );
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <!-- HTML form to send the changes to php -->
    <form method="post" action="file.php">
      <textarea name="config_changes"><?php echo $configFile ?></textarea>
      <button name="save_button">Save</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my code for the config.php

```
<?php

$site_title = "Shopname";
$site_name = "Shopname"; 

$mainpage_header = "Welcome";

$mainpage_content = "Buy A Key"; 

$dbhost = "nolooky"; 
$dbuser = "nolooky"; 
$dbpass = "nolooky"; 
$db = "nolooky"; 

$price1 = "2.50"; 
$price1keys = "1"; 

$price2 = "5.00"; 
$price2keys = "2";

$price3 = "7.50";
$price3keys = "3";

$price4 = "10.00";
$price4keys = "4";

$price5 = "12.50";
$price5keys = "5";

$paypal_email = "myemail"; 
$confirm_email = "myemail";
$fulldomain = "mydomain";

?>
```

Comment: It replaces quotes with forward slashes...?!

Comment: Sometimes problems don't need to be fixed as they can be replaced by clean, and thus easier to debug, ways of doingg what you want to do.
i.e use a database table, or an XML file with PHP DOM functions, or something else, but a client editing a php file ? no, never. If the user has access to the server, he can directly edit the PHP file, and if he doesn't, then you should never allow him to exxecute whatever he wants on the server by letting him put what he wants in a PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Following line will convert double quotes

```
$configFile = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents($file));
```

Can you change it to as below

```
$configFile = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents($file), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have magic_quotes enabled on your server.  Try putting this before you write to the file and if it fixes it, you can either leave it in, or ideally disable magic quotes/upgrade to a newer php version.

`

```
$process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        unset($process[$key][$k]);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
            $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
        } else {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
}
unset($process);
```

}
?>`

Comment: No problem, if it fixed it you should accept the answer so other people with the same problem will know what to try.